# Show that recurrence relation $x_{n+1} = {1\over 2}\left(x_n + {b^2 \over x_n}\right)$ where $x_1 = a >0$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

> Given the following recurrence relation:
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> x_{n+1} = {1\over 2}\left(x_n + {b^2\over x_n}\right) \\
> x_1 = a > 0 \\
> n\in \mathbb N
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Show that $x_n$ is a bounded sequence.

This question follows after [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978064/how-to-show-that-x-n1-fracx-n4-15x-n-bounded-below-and-above-by) so perhaps it may help me solve the linked question.

No constraints on $b$ are given in the problem statement. I've started with $x_n$:

$$
x_{n+1} = {1\over 2}\left(x_n + {b^2\over x_n}\right) \\
x_n = {1\over 2}\left(x_{n-1} + {b^2\over x_{n-1}}\right) \implies \\
x_{n+1} = {1\over 2}\left({1\over 2}\left(x_{n-1} + {b^2\over x_{n-1}}\right) + {b^2\over x_n}\right) = \\
= {1\over 2}\left({1\over 2}\left({1\over 2}\left(x_{n-2} + {b^2\over x_{-2}n}\right) + {b^2\over x_{n-1}}\right) + {b^2\over x_n}\right) = \\
\dots\\
\frac{b^2}{2^1x_n} + \frac{b^2}{2^2x_{n-1}} + \frac{b^2}{2^3x_{n-2}} + \dots + \frac{b^2}{2^nx_{1}} + {a \over 2^n} = \\
= {a \over 2^n} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b^2}{2^{n-k+1}x_k}
$$

So i got:

$$
x_{n+1} = {a \over 2^n} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{b^2}{2^{n-k+1}x_k}
$$

This seems to be correct while i've tested several first terms and they match the initial recurrence. Now I'm wondering how is this even bounded? BTW W|A suggests that:

$$
x_n = b \coth\left(2^{n - 1} \coth^{-1}{a\over b}\right)
$$

Not sure where it's derived from. How do I show this sequence is bounded using precalculus Maths?

Comment: Hello - compute a few sequence terms numerically for $b = 1, 4, 10$ e.g., guess a bound, and prove it by induction.

Comment: I think this is an old fashioned way of approximating $\sqrt{n}$ (where $n=b^2$) and also the result you get if you try to use newton's method to calculate square roots.

Comment: This sequence [was discussed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2384298/find-the-limit-if-it-exists-of-s-n1-frac12s-n-fracas-n) many, [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279523/limit-of-the-recursive-sequence-a-n1-frac12a-n-fracpa-n) ... [many](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n) times on MSE

Comment: @rtybase should i delete the question in such cases?

Comment: It's up to you, but there is a good chance it will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @rtybase ok, i'm voting to close that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that $$a+b\geq 2\sqrt{ab}$$ for $$a,b\geq 0$$